# Nested includes using #as_json fails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm having some problem with this code using the #as_json method.

```
render json: channel.as_json({
     include: {
         gigs: {
             include: {
                 song: {
                     include: [
                         :urls,
                         {
                             artist: {
                                 include: [
                                     :urls
                                 ]
                             }
                         }
                     ]
                 }
             }
         }
     }
 })
```

I'm getting a `undefined method macrofor nil:NilClass` error.

If I remove the `include [:urls]` part in the end a.k.a this code;

```
render json: channel.as_json({
    include: {
        gigs: {
            include: {
                song: {
                    include: [:urls, :artist]
                }
            }
        }
    }
})
```

... everything works perfect.

According to my research the given error is caused by an association problem.
In my case it looks like the artist model isn't associated with the url model, which isn't true.
Running `Artist.first.urls` works fine.

Can anyone figure out what the problem maybe?

I'm using Rails 3.1.1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like it was a bug in Rails 3.1.
My first example that raised an error works in ~> 3.2